# Calculating median in grouped data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, statistics, vbscript

I got stuck when calculating the median age in grouped data (age ranges) for each feature (each feature is a single administrative unit). I have about 18,000 features.
[image: median]

Field names indicate age ranges: 0-14, 15-64, 65-100. In the "median" field I would like to calculate the median age for each feature. 
I found a website https://atozmath.com/StatsG.aspx?q=1 where you can calculate such a median for a single feature, for example the first feature from the attribute table above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The page easily calculated the median for the first feature in the image, and the page also wrote how it calculated it, but I don't know how to write a universal script for a "median" field to calculate the median for each feature.

Comment: Field Calculator should do the job. Add the code you tried with

Comment: I know it can be done with a Field Calculator. The problem is I don't know how to write this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work,

```
def grouped_data_median(t_14, t_15_64, t_65):
    # total number values
    n = t_14 + t_15_64 + t_65
    # median lower bound
    mlb = None
    # groups cumulative frequency before median
    gcfbm = None
    # frequency of median group
    fmg = None
    # class length of median group
    clmg = None
    if t_14 <= t_15_64:
        gcfbm = t_14
        if t_15_64 <= t_65:
            # t_14 <= t_15_64 <= t_65
            mlb = 15
            gcfbm = t_14
            fmg = t_15_64
            clmg = 50
        else:
            if t_14 <= t_65:
                # t_14 <= t_65 <= t_15_64
                mlb = 65
                gcfbm = t_14
                fmg = t_65
                clmg = 36
            else:
                # t_65 <= t_14 <= t_15_64
                mlb = 0
                gcfbm = t_65
                fmg = t_14
                clmg = 15
    else:
        if t_14 <= t_65:
            # t_15_64 <= t_14 <= t_65
            mlb = 14
            gcfbm = t_15_64
            fmg =t_14
            clmg = 15
        else:
            if t_65 <= t_15_64
                # t_65 <= t_15_64 <= t_14
                mlb = 15
                gcfbm = t_65
                fmg = t_15_64
                clmg = 50
            else:
                # t_15_64 <= t_65 <= t_14
                mlb = 65
                gcfbm = t_15_64
                fmg = t_65
                clmg = 36
    return mlb + ((n / 2) - gcfbm) / fmg * clmg
```

In the field calculator you have to invoke the function like this,

```
grouped_data_median(!TOT_0_14!, !TOT_15_64!, !TOT_65!)
```

You can check the formula in the page you get your result.